# git transform my first package's letter from lower case to upper case

Tags: java, github, git-push, uppercase

One of my java project's package is named `rules`. But when pushing to my repo, my package have been renamed to `Rules`.This is a problem because I got errors while compiling(cause of my imports). Why did git do that? Any idea?

Comment: My git doesn't do such things. Do you have any specialities? Custom hooks? Are you sure that this does not already happen _before_ pushing?

Comment: I don't know but I've tried few experiments to see how it reacts.

Comment: When I pull it does not change my package but when cloning my entire project, it does

Comment: Are you using a case-insensitive file system?

Comment: I don't know. How to check out?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information: what is your operating system? What tool do you use to push? (git, Eclipse, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed by removing from index then readdind and push to my repo. Must have been a git bug.